# compare IEnumerable lists and remove duplicates from one of that list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have following model class

```
 public class AssignUserViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<User> Viewrlist { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<User> AssignedViewrlist { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm binding values to it like below. and comparing `objassignuser.Viewrlisttry` and `objassignuser.AssignedViewrlist` then remove duplicate from `objassignuser.Viewrlisttry` like below. but this is not working properly

```
 AssignUserViewModel objassignuser = new AssignUserViewModel();

 objassignuser.Viewrlist = ..
 objassignuser.AssignedViewrlist = ..

 IEnumerable<User> result = (objassignuser.Viewrlist).Except( objassignuser.AssignedViewrlist );

 objassignuser.Viewrlist = null;
 objassignuser.Viewrlist = result;
```

Comment: No , its just a model class , not implementing any interface

Comment: Refer the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example of how to create an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to compare the objects

Comment: `Except` has nothing to do with duplicates, you would need something like `Distinct` for duplicate removal. Can you please provide a minimal example of objects in your lists and the expected result? Make sure to specify, when you are talking about reference equal objects and when it is about content equality.

Comment: @grek40 `IEnumerable<User> Viewrlist` and `IEnumerable<User> AssignedViewrlist` has following properties `UserName`,`ID`

Comment: You need to implement how exactly you want your objects to be compared. By UserName alphabetically? Or maybe by Id numerically? Also ASC or DESC?

Comment: @Daniel I want to compare by User Ids and remove duplicates from objassignuser.Viewrlist

Comment: @StephenMuecke do I need to apply this as `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<User>>` or `IEqualityComparer<User>` ?

Comment: `IEqualityComparer<User>` (and best guess is that you want to compare their ID values)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I created my ObjectComparing class [like this](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/K5REj) but then How to use that on controller class ?

Comment: Give me 30 min and I'll have a look

Comment: @StephenMuecke oky, I tried something like to list distinct users 

`var distinctUsers = (objassignuser.Viewrlist).Distinct(new ObjectCompare());` but no progress

Comment: @kez, That looks fine, except suggest you rename the class to `UserComparer` and assuming the `UserId` property is the unique identifier (PK), then all you really need is `return x.UserId == y.UserId;`. Then the query becomes `IEnumerable<User> result = (objassignuser.Viewrlist).Except( objassignuser.AssignedViewrlist, new UserComparer);`

Comment: @kez a side note to your linked code snippet: `GetHashCode` with `return hashTextual ^ hashDigital` will return `0` every so often, because `hashTextual` and `hashDigital` will be equal. Its not a biggie in terms of functionality, but it means you don't get any benefit from hashing.

Answer (score 0):

You must make the `User` class implement the [`IEquatable<T>` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx).

A simple implementation can look like this:

```
class User: IEquatable<User>
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(User other)
    {
        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

For more info have a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/03/25/how-to-use-linq-methods-to-compare-objects-of-custom-types/).

Comment: oky I changed my model class according to your approach , then what else to do for comparisons ?

Comment: Run your query: IEnumerable<User> result = (objassignuser.Viewrlist).Except( objassignuser.AssignedViewrlist ); it should work. Let me know.

Comment: @kez did you give a try? Please let me know the results